# How do Insert into a table if there is a condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new into sql server and I have created a simple table

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
   FROM sys.objects 
   WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[ODSMasterCustomerLink]') 
   AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [ODSMasterCustomerLink]
Go
Create Table ODSMasterCustomerLink
(MasterCustomerID [int] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES 
ODSMasterCustomer(MasterCustomerID), 
CustomerBaseID [int] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES 
ODSCustomerBase (CustomerBaseID))

select * from ODSMasterCustomerLink
```

These are the results

```
MasterCustomerID    CustomerBaseID
1                      NULL
2                      NULL
```

Now I want to insert multiple values in the CustomerBaseID column using the script below and it says that my insert statement is wrong.

```
If MasterCustomerID = 1 
insert into SMEC_ODS.dbo.ODSMasterCustomerLink
(CustomerBaseID)
values(515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520)
```

The error message is

Msg 110, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.
'

The results that I want is this

```
MasterCustomerID    CustomerBaseID
    1                     515
    1                     516
    1                     518
    1                     519
    1                     520
    2                     NULL
    2                     NULL
```

Comment: Isn't the error message obvious ?

Comment: This is how you can do multi inserts - `INSERT INTO #SQLAuthority (ID, Value)
VALUES (1, 'First');
INSERT INTO #SQLAuthority (ID, Value)
VALUES (2, 'Second');
INSERT INTO #SQLAuthority (ID, Value)
VALUES (3, 'Third');`

Comment: Aren't you looking for `Update` instead??

Comment: Maybe? Im new into sql server.. let me look for an update related question here in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Sql server shows error while inserting multiple records in single query...try this:

insert into SMEC_ODS.dbo.ODSMasterCustomerLink
(MasterCustomerID,CustomerBaseID)
values(1,515)

insert into SMEC_ODS.dbo.ODSMasterCustomerLink
(MasterCustomerID,CustomerBaseID)
values(1,516)

insert into SMEC_ODS.dbo.ODSMasterCustomerLink
(MasterCustomerID,CustomerBaseID)
values(1,517)

insert into SMEC_ODS.dbo.ODSMasterCustomerLink
(MasterCustomerID,CustomerBaseID)
values(1,518)

insert into SMEC_ODS.dbo.ODSMasterCustomerLink
(MasterCustomerID,CustomerBaseID)
values(1,519)

insert into SMEC_ODS.dbo.ODSMasterCustomerLink
(MasterCustomerID,CustomerBaseID)
values(1,520)

insert into SMEC_ODS.dbo.ODSMasterCustomerLink
(MasterCustomerID,CustomerBaseID)
values(1,521)

insert into SMEC_ODS.dbo.ODSMasterCustomerLink
(MasterCustomerID,CustomerBaseID)
values(1,522)

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into SMEC_ODS.dbo.ODSMasterCustomerLink
(MasterCustomerID,CustomerBaseID)

values(1,515), (1,516), (1,517), (1,518), (1,519), (1,520), (1,521), (1,522)
```

More about using INSERT INTO in this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: It says Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: what is it :  If MasterCustomerID = 1 ?
MasterCustomerID  is a variable ?